# Armadillo C++ Auto Type Bad Alloc

Tags: c++, armadillo

Can someone explain why in Debug mode is working okay, but in release i see bad_allocation ?

```
#include <iostream>
#define ARMA_DONT_USE_WRAPPER
#include <armadillo>

int main()
{
    arma::cx_mat testMat;
    testMat.set_size(40, 19586);
    auto nPositions = static_cast<arma::sword>(floor(19586/2));
    arma::cx_rowvec a {19586, arma::fill::randu};
    for ( int i = 0 ; i < 40; ++i)
    {
            // testMat.row(i) = arma::shift(arma::fft(a), nPositions); // very slow
            auto result = (arma::shift(arma::fft(a), nPositions));
            result.print("result");
    }
    std::cout << " i am done \n";
}
```

**( with arma::cx_rowvec is wokring okay, but bad perfomane )**

```
gcc 11.2 
armadillo armadillo-10.8.2
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please post complete minimal working code.

Comment: I posted the code.

Comment: @FurchRadeon Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: `ifftshift` is not used in your code (it is not minimal), there are missing include files, you don't say what version or compiler you are using or what version of armadillo you are using.   Having said that, correcting what it is missing I cannot reproduce the problem with gcc 11.2,  armadillo 10.6.2.

Comment: Sorry. I posted the full version of the code now.
When you try to print what is inside of the result, only in debug mode is working. In Release mode you received "bad_allocation" I am compiling with -O3 in release mode.

Comment: Ok, now I can reproduce with `g++ arma.cpp -larmadillo -O3 && ./a.out`. It looks like a bug in the print function. I guess you can report it.

Comment: In fact if you try to make another calculation with "result value" is the same behaviour.

Comment: Yes, I just realized that there is nothing special about `.print` the problem is that Armadillo produces "expression-templates" which contain a lazy evaluation. It is the likely that such evaluation (that is not performed unless you print or use the result explicitly) is the one causing the segmentation fault. I am not an expert in Armadillo and I am not a fan of lazy evaluation, I would recommend changing the code so the operation is eager (not lazy) so you can debug the problem better, you might just be passing arrays or parameters with the wrong number of elements; the code is hard to read.

Comment: Is possible to share in the example your idea ?

Comment: Do you mean to get rid of lazy evaluation? I don't know the library, I guess you can split your operations and make the types explicit, for example: `arma::cx_rowvec fft_result =  arma::fft(a); arma::cx_rowvec shift_result = arma::shift(fft_result, nPositions));` something like. What are you trying to do? FFT and shift? what is `testMatrix` for?

Comment: Yes, in this case i am trying to do the FFT anf shift. With testMatrix i just tried to use as workaround solution.  The main idea was to request at start point full memory that i needs, and in for loop, just to computer FFT + shift and direct post into the matrix. In idea to avoid to allocate internal for each iteration new cx_rowvec. But i saw that i have bad performance. :(

Comment: One solution is to use : .eval() function, which will enforce result. But again performance not good at all.

Comment: What do you mean that performance is bad? Can you ask a separate question for that?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71344954/armadillo-c-bad-performance-ifft. Done