# Armadillo C++ bad performance ifft

Tags: c++, armadillo, fftw

I have current test code

```
#include <iostream>
#define ARMA_DONT_USE_WRAPPER
#include <armadillo>

using namespace std::complex_literals;

int main()
{
    arma::cx_mat testMat { };
    testMat.set_size(40, 19586);
    auto nPositions = static_cast<arma::sword>(floor(19586/2));
    arma::cx_rowvec a_vec {19586, arma::fill::randu};
    arma::cx_rowvec b_vec {19586, arma::fill::randu};
    arma::cx_rowvec c_vec {19586, arma::fill::randu};

    for (size_t nCo=0; nCo < 3; nCo++) {
        arma::rowvec d {19586, arma::fill::randu};
        for(size_t iDop = 0; iDop < 40; ++iDop)
        {
            
                arma::cx_rowvec signalFi = (b_vec % arma::exp(-1i*M_PI*a_vec));
                testMat.row(iDop) += arma::ifft(arma::shift(arma::fft(signalFi), nPositions).eval() % c_vec).eval();
            
        }
    }
return 0;
}
```

I am trying to perform some computation.
**StopWatch shared performance for each iteration around : 300 ms, which is bad performance for my needs.**

Is someone which can explain what i am doing wrong or some tricks how can i increase the performance.

```
I used .eval() to perform 'eager' evaluation. 
gcc 11.2
armadillo 10.8.2
Release Mode -O3
```

**Updated Version. Is possible to redesign the ifft function ?**
Test Code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fftw3.h>
#include <armadillo>
#include "StopWatch.h"

using namespace std;

inline arma::cx_mat ifftshift(arma::cx_mat const &axx)
{
    return arma::shift(axx, -ceil(axx.n_rows/2), 0);
}

void ifft(arma::cx_mat &inMat, arma::cx_mat &outMat)
{
    size_t N = inMat.n_rows;
    size_t n_cols = inMat.n_cols;
    for (size_t index = 0; index < n_cols; ++index)
    {
        fftw_complex *in1  = reinterpret_cast<fftw_complex *>(inMat.colptr(index));
        fftw_complex *out1 = reinterpret_cast<fftw_complex *>(outMat.colptr(index));
        fftw_plan pl_ifft_cx1 = fftw_plan_dft_1d(N, in1, out1, FFTW_BACKWARD, FFTW_ESTIMATE);
        fftw_execute_dft(pl_ifft_cx1, in1, out1);
    }
    outMat /= N;
}

int main()
{
    arma::cx_mat B;

    B << std::complex<double>(+1.225e-01,+8.247e-01) << std::complex<double>(+4.078e-01,+5.632e-01) << std::complex<double>(+8.866e-01,+8.386e-01) << arma::endr
      << std::complex<double>(+5.958e-01,+1.015e-01) << std::complex<double>(+7.857e-01,+4.267e-01) << std::complex<double>(+7.997e-01,+9.176e-01) << arma::endr
      << std::complex<double>(+1.877e-01,+3.378e-01) << std::complex<double>(+2.921e-01,+9.651e-01) << std::complex<double>(+1.056e-01,+6.901e-01) << arma::endr
      << std::complex<double>(+2.322e-01,+6.990e-01) << std::complex<double>(+1.547e-01,+4.256e-01) << std::complex<double>(+9.094e-01,+1.194e-01) << arma::endr
      << std::complex<double>(+3.917e-01,+3.886e-01) << std::complex<double>(+2.166e-01,+4.962e-01) << std::complex<double>(+9.777e-01,+4.464e-01) << arma::endr;

    arma::cx_mat output(5,3);
    arma::cx_mat shifted = ifftshift(B);
    arma::cx_mat arma_result = arma::ifft(shifted);
    B.print("B");
    arma_result.print("arma_result");
    ifft(shifted, output);
    output.print("output");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: my bet is that ifft is allocating the output array each time it is called. even if that data is moved/copy into the result row. you have to look for an ifft interface that works on output data that is already allocated.

Comment: you mean to use another open source library like fftw3 ?

Comment: Or some Armadillo fft function that can write the output as parameter, I don't know if it exists, `arma::fft(signalFi, out)`. At the end it is likely that everything is implemented in terms of FFTW, but if you want to use it directly then you will have the problem of needing to allocate the plans (FFTW uses plans) which will also reduce performance.

Comment: The canonical usage is to create the plan *and* the output array before the loop and do the FFT operation directly on the `out`. Yes, you loose the nice "functional" syntax (of output as returns of a function on immutable input) but that is the price of performance. If you want to stick to a functional syntax you can but you need to learn how to use special "stack" allocators and things like that.

Comment: @alfC i checked and armadillo do not have any other api for FFT, only to share the input vector/matrix. I would like to try to check if the performance will be increase on this way. Is possible to guide me ? If i understood right, to make allocation before for loop and inside the arma::fft(signalFi, out) to work direct in 'out' ? 
After that how we can add everything in testMat ?

Comment: @alfC i just add updated example with your idea. Could you confirm if i understand right ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242604/discussion-between-furch-radeon-and-alfc).

Comment: I don't know why you call the last code "work on stack allocator", there is no stack allocator there but you are in the right direction in the sense that now you have an out parameter that doesn't allocate. The problem is that `arma::fft(signalFi);` might still be allocating and you might not be able to do anything about that.

Comment: what you can do is to get the internal pointer of the Armadillo arrays, use fftw with raw pointers and std rotate and see what you get. i am very curious what you get.

Comment: Pleas take a look at Sigpack, it has already an integration of FFTW for Armadillo, see example: http://sigpack.sourceforge.net/fftw_loop_8cpp-example.html

Comment: @FurchRadeon, here is the library I measured with https://gitlab.com/correaa/boost-multi/-/blob/master/adaptors/fftw/test/shift.cpp#L45-58

Answer (score 2):

I just tried a similar operation with my own library and, according to my measurements, you are correct that each iteration of the loop shouldn't take more than 1 millisecond (instead of 300 ms).

This is the equivalent code, sorry that this is not an Armadillo answer, I am just pointing out what are the concrete goals for minimizing operations and allocations.

```
#include<multi/adaptors/fftw.hpp>
#include<multi/array.hpp>

namespace fftw = multi::fftw;

int main() {
    multi::array<std::complex<double>, 1> const arr = n_random_complex<double>(19586);
    multi::array<std::complex<double>, 1>       res(arr.extensions());  // output allocated only once                  

    fftw::plan fdft{arr, res, fftw::forward};  // fftw plan and internal buffers allocated only once

    auto const N = 40;
    for(int i = 0; i != N; ++i) {  // each iteration takes ~1ms in an intel-i7
        fdft(arr.base(), res.base());  // fft operation with precalculated plan
        std::rotate(res.begin(), res.begin() + res.size()/2, res.end());  // rotation (shift on size/2) done in place, no allocation either
    }
}
```

The full code and library is here: https://gitlab.com/correaa/boost-multi/-/blob/master/adaptors/fftw/test/shift.cpp#L45-58 (the extra code is for the timing measurement).

What is also telling is that I tried to do all the possible mistakes to pessimize the code.
To try to mimic what I think Armadillo is doing "wrong"... allocating inside the loop and making copies all the time. But what I get is that each iteration take 1.5 milliseconds.

My conclusion is that something is terribly wrong in your Armadillo usage or in the library itself.

```
    multi::array<std::complex<double>, 1> const arr = n_random_complex<double>(19586);  BOOST_REQUIRE(arr.size() == 19586);

    auto const N = 40;
    for(int i = 0; i != N; ++i) {
        multi::array<std::complex<double>, 1>       res(arr.extensions(), 0.);
        fftw::plan fdft{arr, res, fftw::forward};
        fdft(arr.base(), res.base());
        multi::array<std::complex<double>, 1>       res_copy(arr.extensions(), 0.);
        std::rotate_copy(res.begin(), res.begin() + res.size()/2, res.end(), res_copy.begin());
    }
```

Comment: I integrated fftw library. I do not know why with fftw_plan_dft_1d it reads only one coulmn but not full matrix. As result i see only one column. The rest are 0. So maybe i am doiing something wrong ? I used for loop workaround. At this moment

Comment: are you sure you want to change your colptr and not the rowptr?. the C convention is that it is the row which has contiguous memory and therefore amenable to the “simple” interface to fftw you are using. you also seem to keep changing the problem. originally you wanted to generate a single 1D array and repeatedly operate over it. now you have a 2D array and you want to do N 1D ffts.

Comment: Yes, i tried to go deeper to see if is possible to work with Complex Matrix. 
Because i have everything by columns, i used colptr. As i know rowptr is not present in armadillo. Only memptr and colptr
As memptr, i think is possible to work by chunk of col_size

Comment: @FurchRadeon well, ok. but if you use columns they will have an stride different from 1 (probably equal to the row size). in that case you have to use an advanced fftw interface that allows to pass strides. (in my library that is taken care automatically).

Comment: do you have any Readme file how to integrate the library into the project ?

Comment: the library is header only. The README is here: https://gitlab.com/correaa/boost-multi/-/blob/master/README.md#advanced-usage

Comment: Thank you @alfC, i am looking to use your library. In case if i will have some problems to understand, i will try to reach you.

Comment: @FurchRadeon, you can try my library online: https://godbolt.org/z/r85j4ajno